# SoftLayer Object Storage API: Search results are incorrect

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I tried to use softlayer object storage with api-client.
[softlayer-object-storage-php](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-php)

My goal is to search by file name, and to see if the file exists.

singlebyte filename(ex. a.jpg) correct result.
multibyte filename(日本語.jpg) not correct result.

My container is `photo`, no subdirectory.

```
sjc01/photo/a.jpg  
sjc01/photo/日本語.jpg  
sjc01/photo/multibyte_filename.jpg  
sjc01/photo/anytime with space.jpg  
...
```

below code

```
<?php
    include('/includes/lib/ObjectStorage/Util.php');
    $tokenStore = ObjectStorage_TokenStore::factory('file', array('ttl' => 3600, 'path' => '/tmp/objectStorage'));
    #give the write permission in /tmp/objectStorage
    ObjectStorage::setTokenStore($tokenStore);

    $host = 'https://sjc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0';
    $username='SLXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $password='XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $options = array('adapter' => ObjectStorage_Http_Client::SOCKET, 'timeout' => 10);

    $objectStorage = new ObjectStorage($host, $username, $password, $options);
    $containerList = $objectStorage->with('photo')
                            ->setContext('search')
                            ->setFilter('type', 'object')
                            ->setFilter('q.name', "multibytefilename.jpg")
                            ->setMime('json')
                            ->get();
    var_dump($containerList);
```

The result objectCount 100 is incorrect.
I hope objectCount 1.

end of part of return value.

```
["context":protected]=>  
string(6) "SEARCH" 
["containerCount":protected]=>  
int(0)  
["objectCount":protected]=>  
int(100)
```

I need status exists.
Anybody has any idea or correct method?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you query is returning all objects .jpg. Try this:

```
$containerList = $objectStorage->with('test')
                            ->setContext('search')
                            ->setFilter('type', 'object')
                            ->setFilter('q.name', "a.jpg")
                            ->setMime('json')
                            ->get();
    var_dump($containerList);
```

If I am not wrong, you need to specify the property to look for (in this case the name)

here more information about the fields you can use in your query search. http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/API-Operations-Search-Services

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks! a.jpg case is perfect. However, it did not change the multibyte filename of the case. ex.日本語.jpg

Comment: so are you still having issues? well I suggest you to set metadata values to your files, so you can use those metadata to search your files

Comment: Multibyte filename still not searched.They are sent in bulk in ftp client. I can not set the meta data to each file.

Comment: Opps I think multibyte filename is not supported, I suggest you to submit a ticket in the softlayer's portal about that issue.